# How to merge remote branch with the main branch azure repo?

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have a branch like **Myname/taskno1000** and I have finished my task so that one I raised a PR and the branch was merged with the main branch.

Now I have a change request which I need to work on the same branch **Myname/taskno1000**
but I need to take update or merge with the main branch so that I can continue my task on the same branch.

How I can achieve that in Visual studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply rebase Myname/taskno1000 onto main